# Is it possible to test if buffer data was successfully loaded onto the GPU without fully defined shaders? (C++, OpenGL 4.4, GLFW)

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am brand new to OpenGL programming, and I know that graphics APIs are notoriously difficult to debug. My question is, I have a txt file with 3D vertex data. After I create the vertex and index buffers, is there some way to see if the data was loaded correctly? As of now, the only way I can think of is to create a shader to display the points, but to do that would involve a lot of math, and I want to make sure that the data is at least loaded correctly before I try to debug it, that way, if there is a problem, I will know whether or not the problem is in my math in my shader, or I didn't initialize the buffers properly.

Edit:
In case you're confused as to what I'm asking, I'm asking if there is some sort of function you can use that will display the buffer data on the GPU?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`glGetBufferSubData()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetBufferSubData.xhtml) to read back the current buffer content.

Another option is [`glMapBufferRange()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml), which allows you to obtain a pointer to the buffer content.

If you don't know the current size of the buffer, which you will need for the calls above, you can get it with [`glGetBufferParameteriv()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetBufferParameter.xhtml). For example, for the currently bound array buffer:

```
GLint bufSize = 0;
glGetBufferParamteriv(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_BUFFER_SIZE, bufSize);
```